# UI Hang in offline mode

Tags: ios, xmppframework

[image]Does any body know what I need to check if app freezes after some time ? I mean, I can see the app in the iPhone screen but no view responds.

I did some google and i found that, i've blocked the main thread somehow.

But my question is how to identify which method causes blocking of main thread ? is there any way to identify ?

I using XMPP for chat and core data for storing and retrieving the messages.I connect the app with XMPP Server in app delegate class.But i don't know how XMPP Delegate call again and again. According to me core data doing its work fine but in the offline mode XMPP try to disconnect and until it does not complete its task it freeze the app for some time and then works fine in the offline mode.
But I am not sure what is the culprit.I am not able to find the issue.

And i tried the pause button too when it freeze but in the left window i am not able to find which method make the app freeze.

Here is code which i am using

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
  {

  static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"IMChatMessageCell";

  CMMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject *msgInfo = (CMMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject *)[[self messageFetchResultController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

  IMPromos *promo = nil;
  if (msgInfo.promo_Object)
  {
      promo = msgInfo.promo_Object;
      ////NSLog(@"%@", promo);

  }
  else
  {
      promo = [IMDataHandler fetchPromoForPromoID:msgInfo.promo_id];
      msgInfo.promo_Object = promo;
  }

  if (msgInfo.mediaThumbnailPath)
      return [self mediaMessageCell:tableView indexPath:indexPath messageInfo: msgInfo];

  IMChatMessageCell *chatMessageCell = (IMChatMessageCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
  if (chatMessageCell == nil)
  {
      NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:cellIdentifier owner:nil options:nil];
      for (NSObject *obj in objects)
      {
          if ([obj isKindOfClass:[IMChatMessageCell class]])
          {
              chatMessageCell = (IMChatMessageCell *)obj;
              break;
          }
      }

  }
      int imageWith;

  NSString *message = [msgInfo body];

  if (NO == msgInfo.isOutgoing)// left aligned
  {

  ```
     // Just set the textfield here  ///


      NSString* promoImage = [[IMUtils getImageFolderPath] stringByAppendingPathComponent: [chatMessageCell.cellPromo.promo_image lastPathComponent]];
      //NSLog(@"%@",promoImage);

      UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:promoImage];

      if (image)
      {
          chatMessageCell.userImageView.image = image;

          if(!promo.promo_message.length)
          {
              chatMessageCell.userImageView.frame = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(padding, 15, image.size.width,image.size.height));
              bubbleItemOrigin=USER_IMAGE_Y_POS_WITHOUT_HEADER;
              if(!promo.promo_link.length)
                  bubbleItemOrigin-=5;
          }

          else
          {

              chatMessageCell.userImageView.frame = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(padding, USER_IMAGE_Y_POS, image.size.width, image.size.height));
              bubbleItemOrigin=USER_IMAGE_Y_POS;
          }


     }
  ```

  return chatMessageCell;
  }
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
  {

  [self scrollToBottom];
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];

  [self refreshTitleView];
  messagesFetchResultController.delegate = self;
  messageTextField.font = [IMUtils appFontWithSize:font_size];
  }

I am using this code.

When i am running the app without network then it freeze

and  something like this printing into logs
and XMPP'S delegate get called.

Comment: Which thread you are using to communicate with core data. Please ensure that you are accessing core data on secondary thread.

Comment: simply pause the app using debugger to check the stack trace

Comment: @Gagan_iOS there is no need to perform core data operations on another thread since it simply accesses local file storage. Network operations are far more likely to be the problem and they must be completed asynchronously on another thread.

Comment: I paused the app using debugger but not able to found which method or thread is making app freeze.

Comment: can you add the screenshot of the method calls you see after clicking pause ?

Comment: i guess in this case you need to add logs to probably most of your functions and find the last one called before the app hangs